# nginx ERR_SPDY_PROTOCOL_ERROR only on Webkit based browsers

Tags: debian, nginx, ssl

Trying to access my website from `Chrome Version 66.0.3359.139 (Official Build) (64-bit)` I am greeted with the following error:

[image]

Trying with `Firefox 60.0(64 bit)`, it works!

[image]

Version of nginx I am using

```
nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.13.12
built by gcc 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1)
built with OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-compat --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/data/builder/debuild/nginx-1.13.12/debian/debuild-base/nginx-1.13.12=. -specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-compile.specs -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC' --with-ld-opt='-specs=/usr/share/dpkg/no-pie-link.specs -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -pie'
```

curl gives me a `200 OK`

```
curl -I https://v4tailor.com
HTTP/2 200
date: Sat, 12 May 2018 14:49:46 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
set-cookie: __cfduid=d54d82d396e2f2bad73930fda4a6b883a1526136586; expires=Sun, 12-May-19 14:49:46 GMT; path=/; domain=.v4tailor.com; HttpOnly
cache-control: no-cache, private
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000;
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 419db19f1d899a04-EWR
```

The Nginx configuration. I use LetsEncrypt.

```
//nginx.conf
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;

    server_name v4tailor.com www.v4tailor.com;

    # SSL Certificates
    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/v4tailor.com/cert.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/v4tailor.com/privkey.pem";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    # ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;
    #includeSubDomains" always;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

This all started when I switched to LetsEncrypt, initially I didn't realise it since all browsers I use are implemented on the Gecko engine but when I wanted to show my boss the demo, it embarrassingly didn't work -.-.

Initially I was using just Cloud-flare for SSL.

I cleared cache tried to check for it at chrome://net-internals/events. Also tested on different machines.

Googling the error proves difficult due to its vague nature.

**Fix**

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2 default_server;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/main/public;
    index index.php;

    server_name v4tailor.com www.v4tailor.com;

    # SSL Certificates
    ssl_certificate "/etc/letsencrypt/live/v4tailor.com/cert.pem";
    ssl_certificate_key "/etc/letsencrypt/live/v4tailor.com/privkey.pem";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    # ssl_ciphers EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5;

    ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
    ssl_session_tickets off;
    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    add_header Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location /render {
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5000/render;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        }

    location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        # optionally set the value of the environment variables used in the application
        fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
        fastcgi_param APP_SECRET 23kl86a56;
        fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://root:patriot356@@localhost:3306/v4tailor";

        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/index.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
        }


    location /blog {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /blog/index.php?$args;
    }

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

}
```

Firefox was ignoring the Header error but Chrome stopped. Thank you guys!! I wonder how the hell it passed Nginx's configuration tests. This was such a headache.

Comment: There is no need of images, remove them and write in text.

Comment: there is zero code in the images..please stay on topic

Comment: first image shows nothing special this is obvious error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this causes the problem but the following part of the config is definitely wrong:

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;
#includeSubDomains" always;
```

This will result in the following HTTP response header:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
   #includeSubDomains:
```

It looks like you forgot to close the quote in the configuration so that it results in a corrupted header. Some browsers ignore such broken headers, some don't.

Comment: you have sharp eyes. this fixed it. unfortunately i cant upvote